# In etcd v3.0.x, how do I request all keys with a given prefix?

Tags: etcd

In etcd 3.0.x, a new API was introduced, and I'm just reading up on it. One thing is unclear to me, in the `RangeRequest` object. In the [description of the property `range_end`](https://github.com/coreos/etcd/blob/234c30c061a9bf03d4378dd37aad25922c85d62b/etcdserver/etcdserverpb/rpc.proto#L341), it says:

> If the range_end is one bit larger than the given key,
>   then the range requests get the all keys with the prefix (the given key).

Here is the complete text, to provide some context:

```
// key is the first key for the range. If range_end is not given, the request only looks up key.
bytes key = 1;
// range_end is the upper bound on the requested range [key, range_end).
// If range_end is '\0', the range is all keys >= key.
// If the range_end is one bit larger than the given key,
// then the range requests get the all keys with the prefix (the given key).
// If both key and range_end are '\0', then range requests returns all keys.
bytes range_end = 2;
```

My question is: What is meant by

> If the range_end is one bit larger than the given key

? Does it mean that `range_end` is 1 bit longer than `key`? Does it mean it must be `key+1` when interpreted as integer? If the latter, in which encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [PR](https://github.com/coreos/etcd/pull/7206/commits/7e31ddd32a4511c436b14e30ef43756ac782d080) which resolves this confusion.

> If range_end is key plus one (e.g., "aa"+1 == "ab", "a\xff"+1 == "b"),
>   then the range request gets all keys prefixed with key.

UPDATE:

```
var key = "/aaa"
var range_end = "/aa" + String.fromCharCode("a".charCodeAt(2) + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

**One bit bigger than the last byte of `key`.**
For example, if `key` is "09903x", then `range_end` should be "09903y".
There is only **byte stream** when sending to etcd server, so you should care about the serialization of the driver, and determined the value of `range_end`.

Answer (score 0):

A great TypeScript example here: https://github.com/mixer/etcd3/blob/7691f9bf227841e268c3aeeb7461ad71872df878/src/util.ts#L25

work js example with TextEncoder/TextDecoder:

```
function endRangeForPrefix(value) {
    let textEncoder = new TextEncoder();
    let encodeValue = textEncoder.encode(value);

    for (let i = encodeValue.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (encodeValue[i] < 0xff) {
            encodeValue[i]++;
            encodeValue = encodeValue.slice(0, i + 1);

            let textDecoder = new TextDecoder();
            let decode = textDecoder.decode(encodeValue);
            return decode;
        }
    }

    return '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using python aioetcd3. I also encountered the same problem, but I found a way in his source code.

aioetcd3/utils.py         line 14

```
def increment_last_byte(byte_string):
    s = bytearray(to_bytes(byte_string))
    for i in range(len(s) - 1, -1, -1):
        if s[i] < 0xff:
            s[i] += 1
            return bytes(s[:i+1])
    else:
        return b'\x00'
```

usage:

```
await Client().delete([db_key, increment_last_byte(db_key)], prev_kv=True)
```